# How do I reformat my data for ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I have four dataframes (say A,B,C and D). The data in each dataframe is of the format given below. **But each dataframe is of a different length**.

```
 lon       lat           area              fd              tp       rt
-85.40944   41.88833    274.5387    1.100000e+02    50.00000000 60.0000000
-85.40944   41.88833    274.5387    1.140000e+02    31.00000000 83.0000000
-85.40944   41.88833    274.5387    6.040000e+02    76.00000000 528.0000000
-85.40944   41.88833    274.5387    1.000000e+00    1.00000000  0.0000000
-85.40944   41.88833    274.5387    3.340000e+02    32.00000000 302.0000000
```

I want to extract (for example) **FD** columns and the **LON** columns from four dataframes. And after that plot something like this, but instead of one blob, it will be four blobs of Lon v/s FD figures. [image]

Questions:

1. Because of uneven lengths, I am unable to use MELT. How do I do it so that it is easier to plot in ggplot2?

Comment: Why is my question being downvoted? I put so much effort to give detailed explanation of my problem. :(

Comment: I don't understand what `melt` has to do with this. Add a group variable to each data.frame and then `rbind` them.

Comment: Hi Roland, thank you. I have used melt to format data for ggplot before. But never used rbind. Would you mind giving some example code for this? I am in a learning phase. Apologies for being a newbie.

Comment: `rbind(cbind("DF1", DF1), cbind("DF2", DF2), ...)` assuming your data frames are `DF1`, `DF2`, etc.  This will create a single data frame with an extra column indicating the source data frame.  You can then use `facet_wrap` from `ggplot` using the column indicating what original data frame your data came from.

Comment: Do something like `A$g <- "A"; B$g <- "B"; C$g <- "C"; D$g <- "D"; DF <- do.call(rbind, list(A, B, C, D))`. If they don'z have the same columns, subset them first.

Comment: @BrodieG Thanks. I tried, but got this error: **Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names**

However, all names are same. I checked with the identical function and got invalid **'num.eq' value**

Comment: Try: `rbind(cbind(id="DF1", DF1), cbind(id="DF2", DF2), ...)` (note the added `id=`).

Answer (score 1):

```
reshape2::melt(list(A=A, B=B, C=C, D=D), id="fd", meas="lon")
```